# autochecked checkbox with select

Tags: javascript, select, checkbox

hello good is that I was thinking of doing this, the truth that no idea how to do it maybe you can help

By selecting a category the checkbox is activated

**example:**

```
<select> <option value="Juegos"></option> </select>
```

**and my checkbox**

```
<input id="privado" tabindex="7" type="checkbox" name="privado" />
```

*you can activate the checkbox to select that category?*

---

example with image: select category game:

http://screenshotuploader.com/i/1508/0od-n.png

and the checkbox autochecked

[image]

code of select

```
<select id="categoria-select" class="categoria-select" name="categoria" tabindex="3">
    <option value="">Seleccionar categor&iacute;a</option>
    <?php
        $feel = mysql_query("SELECT id_categoria, link_categoria, nombre_categoria FROM categorias ORDER BY nombre_categoria ASC");
        while(list($id, $link, $nombre) = mysql_fetch_row($feel))
        {
            echo "<option class=\"" . $link . "\" value=\"" . $id . "\" " . ($categoria == $id ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") . ">" . $nombre . "</option>\n";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: I'm assuming your previous question was deleted, which is why you're asking the same question again. But you've not answered the questions that were asked on your old question: **1:** what have you tried already (and what went wrong with your attempt)? And **2:** how do the `<option>` elements relate to the checkbox `<input>` elements?

Comment: have you googled for *"javascript how to get select value :stackoverflow"* and *"Select change event in javascript"* or even *"Change dynamically a checkbox state"*? You've could fast easily create a brilliant working code  and *feel good*.

Comment: my apologies if not well use this forum also spoke no English'm using the translator.

What I do is, that when you select the category Games checkbox is activated

Comment: @LinkerosCompartimosTodo they want you to show that you tried to solve the problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: C'mon... instead of pasting `<php>` code that's really meaningless to anyone, paste instead the response you get. Learn to use Developer tools (F12).

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("select_input").onchange = function() {    
    document.getElementById("privado").checked = this.value === "Juegos";
};
```

You can just set `onchange` and see if the value of the `select` tag is "Juegos" and check the appropriate checkbox.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgdb4sj7/1/)

---

To disable the checkbox just do the following..

```
document.getElementById("privado").disabled = true;
```

---

To disable the checkbox when it is checked manually do the following:

```
document.getElementById("privado").onchange = function()
{
    if(this.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("privado").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

If you want to disable it when the select is changed then just add the 
    `document.getElementById("privado").disabled = true;` line to the anonymous function in the original part of the answer.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but people will often downvote answers to questions of poor quality.

Comment: P.S: Why parsing all over again the whole DOM looking for an element that you can easily target using `this` like: `this.value`? All you need is one line: `privadoEl.checked = this.value === "Juegos";`

Comment: @iismathwizard added code and fiddle, hope you don't mind my edit :*

Comment: Also, it would be nice to move the web (JS) forward and use `addEventListener` (for no significant reason in this case :D )

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I dont mind at all. You were polite about it and made a perfectly valid point. Feel free to do as you please :)

Comment: I could do it and thank you very much, now I have a question, you may not be able to disable it once was active check box?

Comment: not but what I say is, that cannot be turned off once

Comment: @LinkerosCompartimosTodo im sorry but I honestly can't understand you. Perhaps try rephrasing what you're trying to say will make it easier to understand.

Comment: Well, I say that once the box is checked can not be changed

Comment: *sigh* let me make a comprehensive edit to my answer that has both ways that I think you're asking

Comment: @LinkerosCompartimosTodo there. I updated the answer. Is any of this what you were trying to ask?

Comment: @LinkerosCompartimosTodo don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you.